# i40e XL710 send packets failed on dpdk19.11, report TX descriptor 219 is not done(port=0 queue=0)

Tags: dpdk

dpdk version : dpdk-19.11

firmware-version: 6.80 0x80003cfb 1.2007.0

NIC:

```
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:05:00.1 'Ethernet Controller XL710 for 40GbE QSFP+ 1583' drv=vfio-pci unused=i40e,igb_uio
```

I used rte_eth_tx_prepare before rte_eth_tx_burst, and rte_eth_tx_prepare returns ok;

I enable TSO offload.

I found the following mailing list, but the issue seems to be inconclusive : http://mails.dpdk.org/archives/dev/2017-August/073154.html

Comment: send failed in here:https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/v19.11/drivers/net/i40e/i40e_rxtx.c#L352

Comment: @J,Heng based on the question, the claim is descriptor is not ready. Can you please share the following details `1) port configuration 2|) Dump the content of the packet for 16B with rte_pktmbuf_dump before tx_prepare and 3) after tx_prepare. ` Please explain `I enable TSO offload` is this SW TSO or HW flag for TSO to be done by NIC?

Comment: @Vipin Varghese thanks for the remainder!  I used rte_pktmbuf_dump found that m->nb_segs value is not correct when tcp retransmit.  I fixed my code and this issue is gone.

Comment: nice to hear it worked out for you. Will update the process for debug and your findings as an answer. Hope it helps others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on the updates from the comments]

Based on the limited logs, the issue lies within MBUF descriptor fields after the update of `tx_prepare`. Hence easiest ways to compare the TX fields of mbuf before and after making the flags changes. Please follow the steps

1. Use DPDK API `rte_pktmbuf_dump`  and dump the packet contents before calling tx_prepare for 16B.
2. After `tx_prepare` invoke DPK API `rte_pktmbuf_dump` for 16B
3. After update of TSO (SW or HW offload), dump the packet contents for 16B using `rte_pktmbuf_dump`

Compare the MBUF fields, especially for TX offloads for anomalies.

1. If FAST_MBUF_FREE is enabled, `n_ref` should be 1.
2. If segments are used, `n_seg` should not be greater than `MAX_SEG supported by NIC`
3. Total `pkt_len` should be equal to the sum of all `data_len` of each chained segment
4. Offload NIC should support flags used.

Note: there is a minimal reason why a TX descriptor will fail for a valid device_configure.

[Update] based on the suggestion, it is updated as `thanks for the remainder!I used rte_pktmbuf_dump and found that m->nb_segs value is not correct when tcp retransmits.` .